# How could you prove that characteristic polynomial $c_{A^{-1}}=\frac {(-x)^n}{detA} c_{A}({\frac1x})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So if $c_{A}=det(\lambda I-A)$,  then $c_{A^{-1}}=det(\lambda I-A^{-1}) $.

I am wondering if there is any identity I can use to solve the equation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** One has: $$c_{A^{-1}}(X)\det(A)=\det\left[\right(XI-A^{-1}\left)A\right]=\det\left(XA-I\right).$$
Besides: $$XA-I=-X\left(\frac{1}{X}I-A\right).$$

Comment: But then where does the $(-x)^n$ come from? It will be great if you could add a little more. Thanks.

Comment: Here you have another hint.

Comment: That's great, thanks

Comment: I found out that without n, the equation is established, but with n, it will be $det(XA-I)=(-1)^{n}det(X^{n}X^{-1}I-X^{n}A)$. How do you determine n?

Comment: Your equality is false, one has: $$(-X)^n\det\left(\frac{1}{X}I-A\right)=\det(XA-I).$$
Don't forget that: $$\forall A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n},\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C},\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n\det(A).$$